# xrandr reverts automatically after a couple of seconds

Tags: brightness, monitor, xrandr

I'm trying to change the gamma on an external monitor, but I find that my `xrandr` command gets reverted automatically after a short period. The duration varies, but it appears to be restricted to between 1 and 4 seconds.

```
xrandr --output DP2 --brightness 0.5
```

What can I do, please?

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i VGA -A2
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [17aa:220c]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

`xrandr --verbose | grep "Bright\|connect` output is the same before and after the change (but not during the change, understandably)

```
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x4a) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm Brightness: 1.0
```

Comment: Please add `lspci -nnk | grep -i VGA -A2` and check if the output of `xrandr --verbose | grep "Bright\|connect"` changed after the monitor brightness falls back into the default modes. You can also try to install and using [ddcontrol](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/ddccontrol).

Comment: Added. The output of the `grep` does not change. I've tried `ddccontrol`, but it tells me "No monitor supporting DDC/CI available."

Comment: What do you mean with "output of the grep" does not change? Could you please show the output at least for the state after the monitor falls back to the default modes.

Comment: I mean that the output of `xrandr --verbose | grep "Bright\|connect"` is the same before and after the change (but not during the change, understandably): `eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x4a) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
 Brightness: 1.0`

Comment: Augh! I have found the issue: [Redshift](https://github.com/jonls/redshift) is periodically overriding all other settings. Well, thank you for your troubles, @Hölderlin

Comment: Oh you are using redshift, I had the same problem and didn't solved it till now. let me know if you solved that issue and please give answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321293/using-redshift-to-adjust-the-brightness). Additionally with respect to your output of `xrandr --verbose` I couldn't see that a second monitor is connected.

Comment: JellicleCat could you (or @Hölderlin) please post an answer explaining that this was caused by redshift so the question can be marked as answered? Alternatively, just delete it if this isn't the question you really meant to ask and ask a new one about fixing the redshift problem.

Comment: @terdon, that is also my opinion, but my flags and edits where ignored and rejected.

Comment: @Hölderlin your flag was neither ignored nor accepted. it was marked as helpful and resulted in a moderator leaving a comment. What more were you expecting? In any case, a flag is not an answer which is what I suggested here. Your edits weren't really celar. Generally edits removing things from the OP are likely to be mistaken for vandalism.

Comment: @terdon I didn't remove text from OP I only removed text from edits of Elder Geek and in each trail of my edits I add the information that the JellicleCat is running redshift.

Comment: @Hölderlin I'm not saying you did anything wrong (you didn't), I'm just pointing out a possible reason why your edits might have been rejected. If you have any more questions, pelase ping me (`@terdon`) in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) so we don't clutter up the comments here.

Comment: @JellicleCat, thank you, this solved my problem, though in my case it was Ubuntu's 'Night light' feature.

Comment: My laptop (HD4600) has the same symptom & cause but it works with `xgamma`. You can set the output monitor using `-screen`, which use the same monitor id as `xrandr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On terdon's recommendation I'll post an answer, but the solution in fact came up in the comments above:

I was running [redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/), and that was constantly managing/overriding the brightness. In the end, I uninstalled redshift, and I only manage my brightness and colour manually now.